# How to define "unit spatial length" in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, measurements, units, length

Suppose I have a metric with *time-independent* $g_{\mu\nu}$. Suppose I have a small measuring rod at some spatial position and I define it to be of unit length. Will it still have unit length when it is rotated over some spatial angle or when it is moved to another position? If not, what is the expression of its length in terms of the $g_{\mu\nu}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it still have unit length when it is rotated over some spatial angle or when it is moved to another position?

Yes, because you've defined it to be so.

(It matters that it's a *small* measuring rod because in general, shapes cannot be rotated in a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian space.)

Comment: Thanks, it becomes a bit clearer. But the time it takes light to travel from one end of this small, thin rod to the other end depends on its position and orientation, is that right?